# when click on edit button record show in edit mode on another tab

Tags: visualforce, outputlink

when click on edit button need to open record in next tab in edit mode its opening my page but its not in edit mode format

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/Population/?id={!st.id}" target="_blank"> 
  Edit
</apex:outputLink>
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to link to the edit view, why is the value a `Visualforce Page`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson first i need to show page like image uploaded it shows perfect now second step is when click on edit button then needed in edit view. thats why vfpage create

Comment: why don't you try directly like this `{!st.id}/e`. This will open your record directly in standard edit view.

Comment: Add 'recordId/e?nooverride=1' in query parameter if your edit screen is overridden with a visualforce page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best practice way to link to a record's edit page is to use the [`$Action`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm) global variable.

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.Edit, record.Id)}">
```

It's not really clear why you are trying to involve a `Visualforce Page` in this equation.

Note that there is a bit more to the syntax of the [`URLFOR`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) function:

> `{!URLFOR(target, id, [inputs], [no override])}` and replace `target` with the URL or action, s-control, or static resource merge variable, `id` with a reference to the record, and `inputs` with any optional parameters. The `no override` argument is also optional and defaults to “false.” It applies to targets for standard Salesforce pages such as $Action.Account.New. Replace `no override` with “true” when you want to display a standard Salesforce page regardless of whether you have defined an override for it elsewhere.
>
> To access a Visualforce page, simple [sic] enter the name of your page preceeded by an “apex/.” For example, if your Visualforce page is named myTestPage, you would use `{!URLFOR("apex/myTestPage"}`.

So if you wanted to ensure the default edit page should be used, you might additionally specify `no override`:

```
URLFOR($Action.MyObject__c.Edit, record.Id, [/*inputs*/], /*noOverride*/ true)
```

Comment: Would be nice if you mention how to pass additional query parameters, if you think that'd be helpful.

Comment: @RahulSharma done.